# É possível colocar um OR na condição de parada do FOR?

Tags: javascript, lógica, condição

É possível colocar duas condições para parar um `for`? No meu exemplo estou tentando fazer isso:

```
function criacaoParidade(entrada) {
    entrada = Array.from(entrada);
    func = positionBit(entrada);

    tam = entrada.length;
    var dic = {};

    for (let index = 0; (index < tam || paridade > tam); index++) {
        var paridade = func[index];
        console.log(paridade)
    }
```

Comment: me parece que o correcto essa situação deveria ser usar um While. ou seja, enquanto que X condição OU Y condição for verdadeira executa o código. acho que é mais isso que você quer.

Comment: Sim pode fazer isso, mas tem de definir a variável paridade fora do ciclo for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ter duas condições não pode, só uma é possível que é a do meio, como já deve saber. Mas pode usar o `||` ou outros operadores, várias vezes. Continuará tendo uma condição, mas a expressão pode ser bem mais complexa, o que importa é que no fim resulte em um booleano. Então pode ter várias expressões comparativas ligadas por operadores relacionais.

Só que no seu caso não faz sentido, é impossível `index` ser menor que `tam`, afinal ela foi declarada valendo `0` logo antes e `tam` é um tamanho que não pode ser menor que `0`. Poderia fazer simples assim:

```
for (let index = 0; index < entrada.length; index++)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/ForArray.js).

Não faz sentido, e geralmente é pior, pegar o tamanho fora do laço. Tem outras coisas bem esquisitas e provavelmente erradas nesse código.